# Python - dictionary with propositions (replace string values)

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, prolog, propositional-calculus

I have some dictionary e.g. of form:

```
my_dictionary = {'A': '¬(p)', 'B': '→(q, ∧(¬(p), ∨(y, z)))', 'Aim': ['p', '→(p, q)']}
```

Is their a simple way to replace all strings appearing in the dictionary values of form `→(q, ∧(¬(p), ∨(y, z)))` or `→(p, q)` by `(q→(¬(p)∧(y∨z)))` or `(p→q)`?

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, if it helped you out.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your post (gives some very helpful hints and links), but its not exactly the answer I searched ... I found now some more or less complicated way (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution by my own using some prolog:

Prolog-file (called "**logic.pl**") has to contain the following code:

```
:-op(800, fx, ~).
:-op(801, xfy, ∧).
:-op(802, xfy, ∨).
:-op(803, xfy, →).
:-op(804, xfy, ↔).


m_Proposition_Binary_x_y(X ∨ Y, X, Y).
m_Proposition_Binary_x_y(X ∧ Y, X, Y).
m_Proposition_Binary_x_y(X → Y, X, Y).
m_Proposition_Binary_x_y(X ↔ Y, X, Y).
```

Now we can define some function:

```
from pyswip import Prolog

def normalize(collection):
    interface = Prolog()
    interface.consult("Prolog/logic.pl")

    if type(collection) is str:
        proposition = collection
        try:
            rest = list(interface.query(f"m_Proposition_Binary_x_y({proposition},A,B)".replace("'","")))[0]
            return f"({normalize(rest['A'])}{proposition[0]}{normalize(rest['B'])})"
        except:
            return proposition
    
    elif type(collection) is list:
        return [normalize(x) for x in collection]
    elif type(collection) is dict:
        old_dict = collection
        new_dict = {}

        for key in old_dict:
            new_dict[key] = normalize(old_dict[key])

        return new_dict
```

With that background its possible to normalize the dictionary very easy:

```
my_dictionary = {'A': '~(p)', 'B': '→(q, ∧(~(p), ∨(y, z)))', 'Aim': ['p', '→(p, q)']}

print(m_str.normalize(my_dictionary))
```

Output:

```
{'A': '~(p)', 'B': '(q→(~(p)∧(y∨z)))', 'Aim': ['p', '(p→q)']}
```

Only problem, for some reason I cant use ¬ instead of ~ with pyswip library (Version: 0.2.11), cause with ¬ I get the curios error:

```
U+ffffffac is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
```

whereby ¬ has unicode U+00AC ..

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be using any of the available [string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0502/) methods or [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Judging from your background in prolog, to handle [first-order logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304726/first-order-logic-engine) properly, you might want to look into using a [FOL parse](https://github.com/shadowbourne/first-order-logic-parser) or full on solving engines, like [pyprover](https://github.com/evhub/pyprover), [pyPL](https://github.com/nclarius/pyPL), [PyLog](http://christophe.delord.free.fr/oldies/pylog/index.html) or [pythogic](https://github.com/marcofavorito/pythogic).